# Recursively nest elements deeper with Angular TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the following array `const tokens: string[] = ['A', 'B', 'C']` and I want to recursively nest them as child of the previous element like this:

```json
[
    {
        name: "A",
        children: [
            {
                name: "B",
                children: [
                    {
                        name: "C",
                        children: null
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

This is my current approach, however, I´m currently running into a `RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded`:

`method.ts`

```js
  private initNode(tokens: string[]): Node {
    let node: node = null!;

    if (tokens && tokens.length > 0) {       // stop if all tokens were used
      const token: string = tokens[0];
      tokens = tokens.splice(0, 1);          // remove the current token from the array

      node = {
        name: token,
        children: [this.initNodes(tokens)]   // set the upcoming node as child (null if all tokens are empty)
      };
    }

    return node;
  }
```

Does somebody know what I'm missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[splice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) return the REMOVED items, not the remaining items. You don't want to assign the return value of `splice` back to `tokens`, but you can assign it to `token` instead.

i.e.

```
const token: string = tokens.splice(0,1)[0];
//no need to assign tokens, it is modified in-place
```

Or you can simply use [`reduceRight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduceRight), no need to write a recursive function.

```js
const output = ["A", "B", "C"].reduceRight((acc,cur)=>{
  return {name:cur,children:[acc]};
},null);

console.log([output]);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the help and also showing the method `reduceRight`. Best regards